# Native App and Azure AD - Hello World

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, identity, adal

I am trying to create a simple example of a console Application that requires a valid user. The Application is a simple Console Application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string authority = "https://login.windows.net/----------------.onmicrosoft.com";
    AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
    Console.WriteLine("Context created");

    string resource = "ConsoleApp1";
    string clientId = "------------------------------------";
    string redirectUri = "http://localhost";

    var parameters = new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.RefreshSession);

    context.TokenCache.Clear();


    // Throws AggregateException--> AADSTS50105: The signed in user is not assigned to a role for the application
    var token = Task.Run(() => context.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, new Uri(redirectUri), parameters)).Result;

    Console.WriteLine("Hello, authorized user");
}
```

The Application starts, presents the sign-in window, and then throws the exception

> AADSTS50105: The signed in user is not assigned to a role for the application

Over in the Azure Portal, I've registered `ConsoleApp1` as a native Application.

Under *Required Permissions*, I've checkmarked:

- Sign in and read user profile
- Access the Directory as the signed-in user

Other than that, I'm stumped, the error Message tells me that I need to assign some kind of role to the user, but I cannot find this anywhere in the Application's settings. Can someone help shed some light on this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were specify the incorrect **resource**(ConsoleApp1). The resource should should represents the resource you have granted to this application and which you acquire the access token for.

It seems that you grant Azure AD Graph's permission to this application, did you want to acquire the access token to use the Azure Graph REST?

If I understood correctly, you can replace the resource using `https://graph.windows.net`.

More detail about integrating with Azure AD, you can refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-integrating-applications).

Comment: That is a great Clue, Fei! My immediate response to this is as follows: The scenario I am after is really just for signing in the user to the Application, and retrieve a minimal set of information about that user in a token. I hope that this token will contain the users claims. Am I correct in assuming this?

Comment: The access token normally used to authorize for the resource. You may call the `https://graph.windows.net/{tenantId}/me?api-version=1.6` to get the user info using the access_token. If you want the application implement the authentication using Azure AD, we can get the **id_token** from Azure AD via OpenId Connect. You can refer [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-desktop) for the code sample. And [this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims) is for the reference for the token issued by Azure AD